# Excel VBA Attempting to set range as columns and call data if criteria is satisfied

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim range_row_aa As Range
Set range_row_aa = Worksheets("Accretion Amort").Range("1:1")

Dim name_column As Range
Set name_column = Worksheets("Accretion Amort").Columns("A:Z")

Dim column_x As Object 
For Each column_x In range_row_aa
  If column_x = "Balance Change Diff" Then
    Sheets("Recon").Range("J3") = "OKKKKK"
  End If
Next
```

If the column on the accretion amort sheet equals balance change diff, I would like to copy/extract the data in that column to the recon sheet.

Would an array be more helpful in this scenario? Perhaps, a function, as I plan to analyze each column in the accretion amort sheet and extract the column data if the column title (all column titles are in row 1) satisfies a criteria.

(Please note the print "OKKKKK" statement is merely a placeholder to test if the For/IF loop worked)

Comment: is name_column actually used anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that loops through Row 1:

```
Sub loopThroughRow1()

Dim range_row_aa As Range
Set range_row_aa = Worksheets("Accretion Amort").Rows("1:1")

Dim cell As Object
For Each cell In range_row_aa.Cells
  If cell.Value = "Balance Change Diff" Then
    Sheets("Accretion Amort").Range("J3") = cell.Address
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

I've used `cell.address` as the placeholder so we know it finds the last instance of "Balance Change Diff"

This will use the clipboard to move values to the second sheet:

```
Sub loopThroughRow1()

Dim range_row_aa As Range
Set range_row_aa = Worksheets("Accretion Amort").Rows("1:1")

Dim x As Integer
Dim cell As Object
For Each cell In range_row_aa.Cells
  If cell.Value = "Balance Change Diff" Then

    cell.EntireColumn.Copy
    x = Sheets("recon").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Sheets("recon").Cells(1, x + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What about the use of an array or function to accomplish